# Migrating Solr Cloud cluster over new cloud vendor

Tags: database, solr, solrcloud

We need to move our solr cloud cluster from one cloud vendor to another, the cluster is composed of 8 shards with 2 replica factor spread among 8 servers with roughly a total of 500GB worth of data.

I wonder what are the common approaches to migrate the cluster but specially its data with the less impact in availability and performance etc..

I was thinking in some sort of initial dump copy to then synchronize them catching up the diff (which could be huge) after keeping them in sync just switch whenever everything is ready from the other side.

Is that something doable? what tools should/could I use?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to replicate the same server structure on the new provider, or just index the same set of data? How do you know if the data has been updated? Is Solr your primary data store (i.e. could you reindex the current state in the background, then send all updates to both clusters for a while)? Do you have a timestamp associated with documents? Have you [looked at the BACKUP/RESTORE commands in the collections api](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-backup)?

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, I was thinking into replicate the same server structure but whatever makes migration easier works for me, that's a good point solr is not our primary data store so we could potentially re-index from there, could I start the re-index process and a bit before finish just start sending new updates? how duplicates entries would be handle? I will look to backup/restore commands as well, thanks!

Comment: Then I would consider re-indexing, it'll allow you to keep both clusters up to date and search the current one while the new one is being built. It'll also avoid any issues between versions and the clusters doesn't have to be identical in their layout.

Comment: Sounds good, how adding duplicates entries would be handle by solr? I mean assuming there will be some overlap between the re-indexing job and the new updates? I guess solr will handle it transparently... What's the best way to verify that both clusters are in sync? any tool/approach available over there? thanks a million

Comment: If you have a timestamp associated with your records, I'd make a note of the current state when starting reindexing, then reindex anything updated after that timestamp .. then do that again, until the delta is 0 (possibly time it with another maintenance task if possible and do the last bit of updates). Duplicate id's will overwrite the previous document, but you can use the `_version_` field to have optimistic updates (i.e. it'll error out if the content has been updated to a more recent version tag than the content you're submitting), but I wouldn't spend time on this yet.

Comment: This information is grand, thanks a lot I think I have a good start point here to start planning and orchestrating the migration. I will try and post any updates on the final approach to share it with the world, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices depending on your existing setup and Solr version:

1. As mentioned earlier, make use of backup and restore APIs from Collections API
2. If you have Solr 6 and above, I would recommend exploring the option of CDCR, which is Solr's native Cross Data Centre Replication.
3. Reindexing onto the new cluster and then leverage Solr Collection Aliasing to change your application end points to the target provider upon the completion of reindexing